# Swift CoreData create or update entity from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, initialization

Hi I'm working with `CoreData` Project and `JSON` response from server. My objective is create an `Entity` `failable` `initializer` from `json` parameter which will first check if `entity` already exist (by check property "id" compare to json["id] field. If entity already exist. the `initializer` will only update entity with `json`. If entity did not exist, the `initializer` will create a new entity and update property of new entity with the `json`.

How can I create the failable initializer?

I have tried this but don't know it is correct or not (Have some unwrap optional.

```
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreData

extension Movie {
    struct Keys {
        static let id = "id"
        static let title = "title"
    }

    convenience init?(in context: NSManagedObjectContext!, with json: JSON?) {

        self.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Movie", in: context)!, insertInto: context)
        guard let json = json else {
            return nil
        }
        id = json[Keys.id].numberValue
        title = json[Keys.title].string

    }

    func update(from json: JSON?) {
        guard let json = json else {
            return
        }

        id = json[Keys.id].numberValue
        title = json[Keys.title].string
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you get a compiler error? What line? What was it?

Comment: Hi there is no compiler error but i dont know it is correct or not. there one more thing there is no checking for exist object before create new entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the init is the right place to look for an existing object.

What I would do is add a class func to Movie that finds or creates a Movie object, something like:

```
/// Returns an existing Movie if the id exists, or a new one if not.
/// Can return nil if json is nil or missing keys
class func findOrCreate(in context: NSManagedObjectContext!, with json: JSON?) -> Movie? {
    // If JSON is nil, return nil
    //  (your code here)
    // Look for an existing movie and return it if you find one
    //  (your code here)

    // If there is no existing one call the init
    return Movie(in: content, with: json)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. So how we combine this. the above initializer is still correct. We just need to add a class func findOrCreate?

Comment: That's what I am suggesting.  Also, you can improve your init by returning nil if the json doesn't have the keys you need.

Comment: Hi can help with the content of findOrCreate. Seem will have some duplicate inside compare to the initializer

Comment: Duplicated code can always be put into other functions.  Get it working first, then try to refactor common code into functions.

Comment: Thanks. Manage to make it work. 1 last question if come to existing movie and need update. How can we only update if has change? compare each value to json or any other way?

Comment: I believe NSManagedObject is smart enough to do that for you.  It keeps track of changed fields and only updates the database on context save if it changes.